Can't get the Previous URL when accessing unautorized page
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{

    private readonly string[] _roles;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        _roles = roles;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        // Check if the user is authenticated
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            RedirectToLoginPage(context);
            return;
        }

        // Check if the user has any of the required roles
        var hasClaims = _roles.Any(role => user.IsInRole(role));
        if (!hasClaims)
        {
            RedirectToAccessDeniedPage(context);
            return;
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void RedirectToLoginPage(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.Path + context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    }

    private void RedirectToAccessDeniedPage(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
 
        var returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
        context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AccessDenied", "Account", new { returnUrl });
    }
}

I have made a custom authorization attribute to handle the unauthorized access, but the problem is the following, when user tries to access the unautorized page(when he is logged in and tries to guess the URL), I want to display a View and in the view, I have the "return the previous page" link, but the problem is that returnUrl is always an empty string in RedirectToAccessDeniedPage method

The code in "RedirectToAccessDeniedPage" is new { returnUrl } which should be new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }.
And you could try get the URL like following
var returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();

context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AccessDenied", "Account", new { ReturnUrl=returnUrl });

Test result


The issue you're facing with context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"] not giving you the previous URL when accessing an unauthorized page is likely due to how browsers handle the Referer header.
The Referer header is not always sent by browsers, especially in scenarios where it might compromise privacy or security. Specifically, when navigating from HTTPS to HTTP or from one domain to another, browsers often omit the Referer header for security reasons.

Store Previous URL in Session: Before redirecting users to the login or access denied pages, store the current URL in session
state.

Retrieve Previous URL from Session: When redirecting back after
authentication or authorization, retrieve the stored URL from
session state.


For example,
private void StoreReturnUrl(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var returnUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.Path + context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
    context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("ReturnUrl", returnUrl);
}

private string GetStoredReturnUrl(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    return context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("ReturnUrl");
}

private void RemoveStoredReturnUrl(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    context.HttpContext.Session.Remove("ReturnUrl");
}

private void RedirectToLoginPage(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var returnUrl = GetStoredReturnUrl(context);
    context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
}

private void RedirectToAccessDeniedPage(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var returnUrl = GetStoredReturnUrl(context);
    context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AccessDenied", "Account", new { returnUrl });
}

